# Creating an Xcode project from existing .C file on GitLAB

Tags: xcode, gitlab, project

I would like to cooperate with someone who is not using xcode. He has created someprogram.c and shared with me via gitlab (I have developer role on that program). As it is just one file I can always use terminal to compile, but I would like to use xcode, but xcode let me just open the file and I cannot compile and run - I guess because I don't have .xcodeproj file.
Solution 1) I will start the project and my partner will just ignore .xcodeproj file.
Is there any other option?

Thank you.

I am just a beginner in both programming and English :(

Edit: just found an answer:
[How to create an Xcode project for an existing GitHub repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26411303/how-to-create-an-xcode-project-for-an-existing-github-repository)

Comment: Yes, just create a Xcodeproj and add the file. Although this means you're not guaranteed to use the same compilation flag between the two of you. You really should decide on a compilation solution (makefile, Xcode, VSCode, etc.) and stick to that.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work for me. The project in xcode looks good, but on gitlab.com pages there are no changes i have made a commited :(

Comment: I think that first solution just works. The problem is that I am completely new to git too. So my commits work but push doesn't. But it can't as it is protected on maintainer's side. As we are both beginners he will just upgrade role for me or better - removes main branch protection so I can push my changes too.